# Nestjs - redis communication between 2 microservices with ClientProxy

Tags: redis, rxjs, timeout, microservices, nestjs

I need a help from somebody experienced. I've built 2 microservices recently (let's call them Amber and Boris) which are communicating between each other using ClientProxy and REDIS. From time to time, when Amber is asking for data from Boris, **it gets timeout Error**.

This is Amber config:

```
constructor(companyName: string, userId: number) {
    this.companyName = companyName;
    this.userId = userId;

    this.client = ClientProxyFactory.create({
        transport: Transport.REDIS,
        options: {
            retryAttempts: 0,
            retryDelay: 0,
            url: 'redis://<some_url>:<some_port>,
        },
    });
}
```

Then request-response:

```
private async sendRequest(pattern: string, payload?: object): Promise<any[]> {
    payload = payload || {};

    try {
        const result = await this.client.send(
            { type: pattern },
            { userId: this.userId, companyName: this.companyName, ...payload}
        )
        .pipe(
          timeout(30000),
          map((response: any) => { // Success...
              return response;
          }),
          catchError((error) => { // Error...
              return throwError(error);
          }),
        )
        .toPromise();

        return result;

    } catch (err) {
        Logger.error('Couldn\'t get data from Boris service: ' + err.message)
    }
}
```

Then on Boris service, I have basically just Controller set with @MessagePattern and I'm just returning data:

```
@MessagePattern({type: 'getAvailableCases'})
findAll(@Payload() data: object): Promise<object> {
    this.assignPayload(data);
    return this.getData();
}
```

Important to say, Boris service is doing queries to database in order to return data. But on db side seems there is no problem.

What I'm interested in the most is:

1. whether I have **ClientProxy** set up properly
2. whether I have answer processing set up properly **with pipe()** and **toPromise()**, as I'm not well familiarized with ClientProxy and RxJs.

Thank you a hundred times for any response!

Answer (score 0):

Turned out, the ClientProxy wasn't releasing connections to Redis after the communication is done. This way, the number of connections was increasing until there was no connection left.
The solution is to close connection after the data are returned:

```
this.client.close();
```